# OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, playframework

I seem to be getting this exception:

```
Execution exception
InvocationTargetException occured : null

play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:239)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:557)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:508)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:484)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:479)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:161)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2367)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:130)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:114)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:415)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:132)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:106)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:63)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:63)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:63)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:63)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:63)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:63)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:63)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:63)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:63)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)
```

My code is:

```
"".equals(question.uniqueID)
```

where question is a model and uniqueID is a String. I'm using play framework 1.2.6 and this is totally unexpected. SO is asking for me to write some more text so I'm trying.

Comment: Increase the permgen space when you start your program -XX:MaxPermSize so that it can consume more memory

Comment: This looks rather like a play framework bug then an actual heap space problem.

Comment: This question describes what the error means: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/what-does-the-error-message-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-excee

Answer (score 1):

> My code is: "".equals(question.uniqueID) where question is a model and uniqueID is a String.

That doesn't match he stack trace so I don't this is the cause of an OOME.

> I'm using play framework 1.2.6 and this is totally unexpected.

You can run low on memory in any system, esp a high level one like Play, so not that unexpected.  The first thing I would try increasing your maximum heap size to at least 1 GB if not 16 GB (if you have that much)

Comment: Yes, it does not match the stack trace, but it happens on that exact line - when I debug and step, this is where it freezes for 10 seconds and then gives me the exception. This is the single point that when I comment out, it starts working again. The fact is, of course, caused by play's stupid byte code enhancement.

Comment: @twihoX can you try more heap?